# Compare two tables on one column not matcching and giving alternate rows- sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

My requirement is as below,

[image]

I need data to be compared from two identical tables where version name is given & all other columns match except [Value].
It is required to be displayed in alternate rows with "YES" "No"

My query:

```
Select  [Versions],[Profile],Value,[Step1],[Step2],[Step3],[Step4],[Step5],[Step6],[Step7],[UploadedBy] 
from 
(
SELECT a.[Versions],a.[Profile],a.[Value] ,a.[Step1],a.[Step2],a.[Step3],a.[Step4],a.[Step5],
a.[Step6],a.[Step7] ,a.[UploadedBy],a.[UploadedOn] FROM [CREP].[dbo].[T_CRI_RollenProfile_CurrentProfiles] as a 
inner join [CREP].[dbo].[T_CRI_RollenProfile_MasterProfiles] as b 
on  
( a.[Profile]=b.[Profile] and a.[Step1]=b.[Step1] and a.[Step2]=b.[Step2] and a.[Step3]=b.[Step3] and 
a.[Step4]=b.[Step4]and a.[Step5]=b.[Step5] and a.[Step6]=b.[Step6] and a.[Step7]=b.[Step7])  
where  a.Value<>b.Value and  a.[Versions]='Current_20150318_v2'  
union 
SELECT a.[Versions],a.[Profile],a.[Value] ,a.[Step1],a.[Step2],a.[Step3],a.[Step4],
a.[Step5],a.[Step6],a.[Step7] ,a.[UploadedBy],a.[UploadedOn] 
FROM [CREP].[dbo].[T_CRI_RollenProfile_MasterProfiles] as a 
inner join [CREP].[dbo].[T_CRI_RollenProfile_CurrentProfiles] as b  
on ( a.[Profile]=b.[Profile] and a.[Step1]=b.[Step1] and a.[Step2]=b.[Step2] and a.[Step3]=b.[Step3] 
and a.[Step4]=b.[Step4]and a.[Step5]=b.[Step5] and a.[Step6]=b.[Step6] and a.[Step7]=b.[Step7]) 
where a.[Versions]='Master_20150318_v4' and a.Value<>b.Value) as data  
group by [Profile],[Step1],[Step2],[Step3],[Step4],[Step5],[Step6],[Step7],[Versions],Value,[UploadedBy]"
```

Could some one help.? I am not getting the required output. I don't know where I am missing out..on joings

**Table structures & conditions**

```
[dbo].[T_CRI_RollenProfile_CurrentProfiles]  a.[Versions]='Current_20150318_v2'
[dbo].[T_CRI_RollenProfile_MasterProfiles] a.[Versions]='Master_20150318_v4'

a.[Profile]=b.[Profile] and a.[Step1]=b.[Step1] and a.[Step2]=b.[Step2] and
a.[Step3]=b.[Step3] and a.[Step4]=b.[Step4]and a.[Step5]=b.[Step5] and 
a.[Step6]=b.[Step6] and a.[Step7]=b.[Step7])where a.[Versions]="[]" and a.Value<>b.Value
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.) Besides, if you format your code better someone might even care to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell with no data to examine, but this looks like it may be the same thing. Just one unnested query, busy but simple.

```
SELECT  a.Versions, a.Profile, a.Value, a.Step1, a.Step2, a.Step3, a.Step4, a.Step5,
        a.Step6, a.Step7, a.UploadedBy
FROM    CREP.dbo.T_CRI_RollenProfile_CurrentProfiles as a 
join    CREP.dbo.T_CRI_RollenProfile_MasterProfiles as b 
    on  a.Profile = b.Profile
    and a.Step1 = b.Step1 
    and a.Step2 = b.Step2 
    and a.Step3 = b.Step3 
    and IsNull( a.Step4, 'null' ) = IsNull( b.Step4, 'null' )
    and IsNull( a.Step5, 'null' ) = IsNull( b.Step5, 'null' )
    and IsNull( a.Step6, 0 ) = IsNull( b.Step6, 0 ) -- if step6 is a numeric field
    and IsNull( a.Step7, 'null' ) = IsNull( b.Step7, 'null' )
where   a.Value<>b.Value 
    and a.Versions in( 'Current_20150318_v2', 'Master_20150318_v4' )
order by Profile, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7, UploadedBy, Value desc;
```

In your screenshot, Step3 is shown twice, once with data and once without. From the two whole rows shown, I had to assume that if the fields showed data, it was NOT NULL. So, assuming you wanted a NULL in the same field from both tables to count as the same value, you have to use `IsNull`. For the second parameter, use a value that cannot be found as an actual value in the field. And it has to be the same type as the field. So if, as shown, Step6 is a numeric field, the second parameter also has to be numeric. I show zero but if that is a possible actual value, choose something else.

What I don't understand is the grouping. Is it possible to have more than one row in a table with the same data in all fields and you want to merge them into one output row? I'm guessing not, but if so, it's easier just to add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT`.

You do want to `order by` all the fields, *except for* `Versions`. The `Value` field should be last and descending -- 'Yes' before 'No'.